# Dot/Room-Specific Alexa Skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an Echo Dot in my bedroom and an Echo Dot in my living room. I also have Philips Hue lamps in both rooms. I want to be able to walk into my living room and say "Alexa turn on/off the lights" and it would turn on/off the lights in my living room only. And I would like to go into my bedroom and say "Alexa turn on/off the lights" and it would turn on/off the lights in my bedroom only. Keep in mind that I have 2 Echo Dots.

Is that possible?

Comment: As written this doesn't seem like a programming question to me, but if you identified the language and specific APIs you were working with then maybe you could ask about appropriate strategy for those tools?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this works out of the box using the mobile app (an NOT with the web app). You can simply create a "group" and assign your echo dot to it. You don't need to implement you own skill. See https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201749250